# Ionic - Uploading new version to Google Play Dev results in error

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play, apk

I've built an Ionic app and want to upload a new version to the Alpha Track in Google Play Dev Console. I changed the version in config.xml as explained in [Cordova docs on config.xml](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref/index.html#additional-versioning)

```
<widget id="nu.velt.tuintalent" version="0.0.2" android-versionCode="2" .....
```

When running gulp build-android, it indeed updates the versionCode and versionName in the AndroidManifest.xml as you can see in the snippet below.

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="0.0.2" .....
```

After signing and running zipalign, I try to upload the APK in Google Play Dev Console. There I get the error that the upload failed.

> You need to use another versioncode for your APK because you already have an APK with verionscode 1.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify `versionCode` and  `versionName` of generated APK. Run this commond-

```
aapt dump badging myapp.apk
```

`aapt.exe` is in build-tools dir.

Comment: Indeed, the versionCode and versionName are still 1 and 0.0.1 respectively.  But I have no idea how I can change this, besides doing this in the config.xml. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: what is your cordova version? did you try reinstalling platform?

Answer (score 1):

Previously I built the APK with a Gulp command like

```
gulp build-android
```

When I tried building the APK with the following command, the version was correctly updated

```
ionic build --release android
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.